# Castle Activerecord: FindAll() by children / Use Foreign key Ids in Expression

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord, nhibernate-criteria

I need to query based on child objects of an ActiveRecord class (`FindByFleetAndJob()`, below).  Normally I would use instances of the objects but in this case I don't have them, and don't want to do two visits to the database just to get objects for a query.  I have attempted the following, creating dummy objects for the expressions:

```
[ActiveRecord("Alerts")]
public class Alert : ActiveRecordBase<Alert>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("AssociatedFleetId")]
    public Fleet AssociatedFleet { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("AssociatedJobId")]
    public Job AssociatedJob { get; set; }

    ...

    public static Alert[] FindByFleetAndJob(int fleetId, int jobId)
    {
        var criteria = new List<ICriterion>();
        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("AssociatedFleet", new Fleet { Id = fleetId }));
        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("AssociatedJob", new Job { Id = jobId }));
        return FindAll(criteria.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I have successfully done this with other queries but for some reason this one throws:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing. Type: DataObjects.Job, Entity: DataObjects.FCJob#123

So my question is either, is there a way to combat this exception, or is there a way to alter the query to just pass the ids of the child objects, rather than objects themselves?  Doing the following, understandably, does not find a property of name AssociatedJobId:

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("AssociatedJobId", jobId));
```

although this is basically what I want to achieve.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following code, but I am **so** not sure if it is correct:

```
  return FindAll(
      Subqueries.PropertyIn("AssociatedFleet", DetachedCriteria.For<Fleet>().Add(Expression.Eq("Id", fleetId)).SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id")))
    , Subqueries.PropertyIn("AssociatedJob", DetachedCriteria.For<Job>().Add(Expression.Eq("Id", jobId)).SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id")))
    );
```

Greetings
Juy Juka